# How to build a dynamic json object array using angularjs?

Tags: angularjs

I have declared it as below and also showing data is actually coming from the server but the following code doesn't work if there are multiple arrays in the data coming from the server.

```js
$scope.items = [
{
  id: “”,
  locations: [{
     name: “”
  }]
}
]

Data from server looks this way.

  $scope.data = [
  {
    id: '1',
    type: 'a1',
    year: '1999',
    locations: [
      {id:'1', name: 'abc'},
      {id:'11', name: 'xyz'}]
  },
  {
    id: '11',
    type: 'a2',
    year: '2000',
    locations: [
    {id:'22', name: 'abc1'},
    {id:'23', name: 'xyz1'},
    {id:'24', name: 'efg1'}]
  }
...
]
```

```js
 for (var i=0; i<$scope.data.length; i++)
    {
     $scope.items[i].id = $scope.data[i].id;
        for(var j=0; j<$scope.data[i].locations.length; j++) {
             $scope.items[i].locations[j].name = $scope.data[i].locations[j].name;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have done something like this earlier.

I created a function which would return a json object which in your case would be like

```
$scope.getJson = function(){
     return { 
         id: “”,
         locations: []
     }
}
```

Now you have to modify your loop a little bit to handle multiple `JSONArray` elements like

```js
 for (var i=0; i<$scope.data.length; i++){
     var temp = $scope.getJson();
     temp.id = $scope.data[i].id;
     temp.locations = $scope.data[i].locations;
        
     $scope.items.push(temp);
 }
```

If you want to copy some specific properties from `$scope.data[i].locations` only, then you can use another loop else you can assign the locations array directly.

Comment: Hi Amit! I have added the sample output array as how it looks like. So locations is dynamic as well. And there can be multiple items in the data array

Comment: Btw, why don't you simply try assigning server data as `$scope.items = $scope.data;`

Comment: I actually have additional fields in server data which I don't need. Please check the updated server data. I tried your solution but doesn't work for me.

Comment: Try the above solution, it should work for different sized `locations` array too!

Comment: Thanks! Works great